# Unable to get the correct hours:minutes string from NSDate() in Swift

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Always prints 11:04 , any ideas on whats wrong with this code to return the current time in hours:minutes ?

```
import UIKit

extension NSDate {

    func currentTimeInHoursAndMinutes() -> String {

        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
        dateFormatter.timeZone =  NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:MM"
        let timeStr = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(self)
        print("timeStr:\(timeStr) for nsdate:\(self)")
        return timeStr
    }
}

let time = NSDate().currentTimeInHoursAndMinutes()
```

Comment: Show the whole print line, and how you're creating the date you call this on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using months instead of minutes, for the rest of this hour it will appear to be the same time if you keep using the month.

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
```

[Unicode Date Format Patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns)